# How loop through multiple divs in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to do a scrapper in python, but the tiles update dynamically the class, so my option is to use xpaths. The problem is that in the dibs, they change between cards for example.

Card title 1 have x path

```
//*[@id="component_2"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]
```

but title 2 have xpath

```
//*[@id="component_2"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]
```

the second div changes through a list, so my question is, there's is any way to loop through those divs, mantaining the final path?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please [edit] post the  with relevant html or url and your expected out from it. Without relevant html or url it is very difficult for contributor to write proper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. code:

```
base_xpath = '//*[@id="component_2"]/div/div[{0}]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]'
for i in range(1, 5):
    # Replace the 2nd div index with the variable
    xpath = base_xpath.format(i)
```

**NOTE:** Change the range in for loop according to your requirement.

Comment: There's no way that automatically search those div that have the path? Cause im using pagination and the website is very dynamic on how show the results. Thanks for your answer btw!!

Comment: Sorry! But, I'm not very clear with your rquirement!!! Do you want to search for all the div elements in the page?